# How to calculate complexity of this recurrence?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence, master-theorem

I have this recurrence:

[image: equation]

I want to apply the [Master Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) because it seems to belong to the *Case 1*, so I want to probe that:

[image: equation]

But I don't have any clue about how can I do it. Am I on the right way ?

Comment: In the Wikipedia page, the second example under "Inadmissible equations" looks similar to yours. The ratio `f(n)/n^log(b,a)` for your equation is the same as the example, `1/log(n)`. Hence, Master Method does not apply.

Comment: @Aziz i see.. any idea how to solve it then?

Comment: @jscherman Is the official answer O(n^2).

Comment: @SumeetSingh and how have you came to that ?